# want to create a calendar which is in my application scope

Tags: iphone, ios, calendar

i want to use a calendar template in my app. It should not be connected with native (Device) calendar. I will get/put events from my server. It should not access the native calendar's events. I just want to create a calendar which is in my application scope? How can i do this? Is there any tools available? 
I tried Tapku and Kal . But it is accessing native calendar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not possible with the iOS provided API; you will have to roll your own implementation.

https://github.com/devinross/tapkulibrary - TapkuLibrary contains the tools for both a month view and a day view, similar to the iOS native calendar. You will have to provide it with data from your server.

Comment: Thanks Leo Natan.I have 2 questions.1. what is the date format i have to use in tapku library?i am getting from my server like this 2012-12-12 16:30:00. But it is not working. How to pass our date value into it?
 TKCalendarDayEventView *eventViewSecond = [TKCalendarDayEventView eventViewWithFrame:CGRectZero  id:nil startDate:[[NSDate date]addTimeInterval:60 * 60 * 2] endDate:[[NSDate date]addTimeInterval:60 * 60 * 5]    title:@"title" location:@"place"];

Comment: 2.In day view is it accepting only today's date alone? 
  - (void)reloadDay
{
 // If no current day was given
 // Make it today
 if (!self.currentDay) {
  // Dont' want to inform the observer
  _currentDay = [NSDate date];
 }
If i give date other than today's date then will it be worked?

Comment: @Eswari Apologies, I am not very familiar with the tapku library. I recommend asking on the github discussion board.